# Polynomials and composition of functions

Tags: calculus, polynomials, function-and-relation-composition

Is there a finite set, $M$, of functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that any polynomial $P\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be expresed as a composition of functions from $M$?

For example I can do the following.

Let $\left \langle M \right \rangle$ be the set of all functions which can be expressed as a composition of functions from $M$. There are infinitely many primes $p_i$ such that: $p_ix = f_1\circ g_i\circ f_2$, where $f_1,f_2\in M$ and $g_i\in \left \langle M \right \rangle$. So $f_2$ is an injective function and $f_1$ is a surjective function...

Comment: I guess so. Take the zero function, addition, and multiplication.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions of one variable.

Comment: They can't all be polynomials because deg(fg)=deg(f)deg(g) so you can't get a polynomial of prime degree greater than the degree of the highest degree polynomial in $M$

Comment: The set of all compositions of a finite set of functions is countable.

Comment: @ Yes, it is. But $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is also countable.

Comment: @alphacapture 1) functions of $M$ should not be polynomials; 2) We must be able to construct all $P\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by using $M$, but it does not mean that with functions from $M$ we cannot get somthing else, $e^{\sin x+\pi}$ for example.

Comment: @Tzara_T'hong  I am aware; just noting stuff that might be useful. In fact even the set of polynomials with integer coefficients of degree 3 cannot be generated by a finite number of polynomials.  Proof: If the composition of some polynomials is degree 3, it must be the composition of a linear, a cubic, and a linear function.  But the ratio of the zeros of the derivative are not changed by the linear functions, and there are infinitely many possible such ratios over all cubics, so there must be infinitely many cubics in $M$.

Comment: In fact even linear functions cannot be generated by a finite number of polynomials with a leading coefficients argument: If $M$ is finite, there are a finite number of leading coefficients.  The nth smallest element of the set of products of these is asymptotically exponential in n, contradiction.  I think this argument also shows that $M$ cannot be a finite number of rational functions either.  So perhaps one can ask your question for linear functions instead of all polynomials...

Comment: In fact the argument in my previous comment shows that $M$ cannot consist only of functions each asymptotic to $cx^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ (where the $\alpha$ can be different for different functions).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha_0\colon\mathbb{R}\to (0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bijection, then $\alpha_k=(x+1)^{\circ k}\circ\alpha_0\colon\mathbb{R}\to (k,k+1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is also bijection. Let us somehow enumerate the set 
 $\mathbb{Z}[x]=\{P_k |\ k\in\mathbb{N}_0\}.$

Define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows. $f\big|_{(k,k+1)}(x)=P_k\left(\alpha_k^{-1}(x)\right)$ and $f(x)=0$ for the remaining. Now it is quite easy to see that $$P_k=f\circ (x+1)^{\circ k}\circ\alpha_0.$$